# Python block a key on keyboard and log it

Tags: python, logging, keyboard

I'm wanting to prevent the default action of pressing `w` on the keyboard, but when I do press w, I want to be able to log it. `keyboard.block_key("w")` wont let me log it

```
import keyboard
while True:
    keyboard.block_key("w") #prevents the default action
    print(keyboard.read_key()) #but I want to still be able to read when I press it
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code `block_key` is simply calling

```
hook_key(key, lambda e: False, suppress=True)
```

You can simply create your own `block_key` function

```
import logging

def log_key(e):
    logging.info(f’key {e.name} is pressed’)
    return False

def block_and_log_key(key):
    hook_key(key, lambda e: log_key(e), suppress=True)
```